# NET Service Solution

Tags: .net, asp.net, wpf, silverlight, service

I want to make an application that separate interface, business process and database.

The idea is I want to reuse business process and database part in different interface.

for quick example...

In the first project, I use Silverlight as my interface
In the second project, I want to use WPF
In the third project, I want to use ASP NET
(All is .NET technology and same application)

Can anyone tell me what should I use for business process part, so I can reuse the business process part in all project?

Answer (score 1):

Write your middle tier using webservices

```
WCF or .asmx
```

you can call webservices from all kind of UI you are looking for

Comment: Does WCF service is consumable by silverlight, asp.net, wpf, and old windows form ?

Comment: Well. Mr. Kobe, After I thinking of the way to implement the web service using WCF service application... There is a thing that I want to know. How Can I secure the service, so there is only member who already login to my app that can called the service, and only my application that called the services?\

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dll named "BusinessLogic.dll" which contain all your business logic code and reference this dll in all projects

Comment: Thanks for your advice Mr. Samir, But I think I will use web service in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For the business layer, I would recommend WCF (since all the UI's are .NET, this gives you the most flexibility).  You can do this one of two ways:

1. A WCF Class library (essentially a WCF DLL)
2. A WCF Class library or application that sits on top of an old fashioned DLL.  This would enable you to use the business logic directly in an application, but I think #1 is the best route to go.

You can do something similar for the data access layer, as well, or you can simply implement the data access layer as a DLL that is directly referenced (with no intervening WCF/Web Service) by the business layer.  However, using WCF to access the data layer gives you some flexibility in terms of not having to physically co-locate the business layer and data layer.

You will also, more than likely, discover that some classes can be used by multiple layers during your design and development.  I generally put those into a separate assembly, and reference it as needed in the various layers to prevent writing the same code over and over.

Comment: Thankyou for your advices. I will try WCF as my solution